# What are some standard setups people are using to work with GitHub?

Tags: git, process, installation, github

In other words, how do people work with Git?

I just finished uploading my first project and it was far from being a straightforward task, anyway once the thing is up and running what would be a good configuration?

I cannot see how people could rely on the GitGUI or command line for their professional development work or worse code straight into the browser - but I am sure I am missing some thinghuge here.

Also, Is there any third-party client better than the GitGUI?

Please, enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use git via the command line for all of our work, which includes large projects with many (10+) developers.

Typically, we host a remote repo on Github, work in Textmate, and keep a Terminal window open cd'd to the app directory from which we work with git.

This setup works very well - I've never needed to use any of the GUI apps to interact with git.

When working with other developers, the only time we get merge conflicts is when we're working in a similar area, however, regular pushing to the remote repo, and appropriate branching tends to minimise this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do indeed use the command line for my Git (and github) work, with gitk as my repository browser (which I find indispensible) and Emacs as my editor.  My main interaction with github is pushing commits, which is pretty straightforward on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I work only with the git command line, only rarely using gitk or tig to look at some fancy graphics. I guess I haven't gotten into real big projects to have the need to visualize the history like that. My text editor is vim, and all my other tools are also command line based. As the github guide explains quite clearly, it's easy to set up the remotes so that you can have seamless integration without even needing the browser.

Comment: sounds like a nice setup - wonder if it would be scalable for big projects where large teams need to constantly resolve merges and all that

Comment: could you provide links for gitk and tig?

Comment: The backend tool for everything is git itself, so the functionality you get is pretty much the same. The setup used is the preference of the individual developer, and probably has nothing to do with anyone else.

tig: http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/
gitk: http://gitk.sourceforge.net/